# How to capture the clusternames in the below arraylist using groovy

Tags: arraylist, groovy

jsonResponse: [clustername1=Succeeded, clustername2=Succeeded, clustername3=Succeeded, clustername4=Succeeded]

I am trying to hit one get url to get clusternames and above is the response i got

now i want to list the clusternames that are Succeeded and save into a variable "clusterNames"

Comment: Hiya! That's not valid groovy, nor is it a valid list. Can you try to more clearly explain what you have, what you want, and where you're struggling?

Comment: def resp = execution.getVariable("jsonResponse")
    if (!resp.success) {
      logWarn("$resp.statusCode and error $resp.errorString")
    } else {
      def list = resp.content.clusterIds
      logWarn("$list")
    }
} finally {
    execution.setVariable("clusterNames", clusterNames )
}

Comment: @hari87 I think https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/f043318f6d7bdb53516dd78531e1ca17 is what you just posted in that comment.

Comment: yes that the code and my $list is giving below response 

[clustername1:Succeeded, clustername2:Succeeded]

i need to capture all the clustername*